# CSS grid & Sass

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

The CSS working group member Rachel Andrews mentioned in a conference video that Sass is compatible with the new CSS grid spec.  With that, does anyone know the syntax for spacing the "ASCII art" on grid-template-areas for Sass?  I've since checked the Sass documentation and couldn't find anything (yet).  The errors I get involve spacing.  Appreciate any pointers in the community.  If not, back to .css until then (:  Thanks...

```css
.wrapper
    grid-template-areas: header
                         nav
                         image
                         lead
                         cta //errors occur here with ASCII art grid areas for CSS grid
                         
.header-area
  grid-area: header
  
.nav-area
  grid-area: nav
  
.image
  grid-area: image
  
.lead
  grid-area: lead
  
.cta
  grid-area: cta
```

Comment: So CSS grid-template-areas ASCII art works fine with .scss syntax, just not .sass after toying with it.  Of course .scss is identical to CSS.  Was hoping .sass would work to keep it cleaner.  If anyone knows any discussion going on about .sass working here (or secret hacks to make .sass work with the ASCII portion of grid-template-areas), would love to check out... Thanks in advance...

Comment: Robert, I always use the SASS syntax, but there are occasions that the use of SCSS is demanded. I just bite the bullet and write SCSS.

Comment: @Brad have you been successful using .sass with the CSS grid ascii art layout feature?  If so, seeking the syntax (see comment in code above where it breaks).  It works fine in .scss form.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no used the grid ascii art layout. But I would imagine it would work just fine

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Grid template areas must be quoted. Each row is a single string:

```
  grid-template-areas: "header header"
                       "main   sidebar"
                       "footer footer"
```

full [working demo here](http://codepen.io/keithjgrant/pen/ZeVRQO?editors=1100)

---

**edit** The above example no longer works, I think due to changes in newer versions of Sass. It cannot handle the multi-line expression ([issue here](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/216)). Each grid row must be defined all in the same line:

```
.grid
  display: grid
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "main sidebar" "footer footer"
  grid-gap: 1em
```

The linked demo on codepen has been updated to match. If you use the SCSS syntax (with braces & semi-colons), there isn’t this limitation.

Comment: Thanks Keith.  A simple fix to make a world of difference! The working demo was perfect.  Best

Comment: @atilkan Remove the spaces between items in the grid-template-areas.

Comment: @RenatoFrancia Do they have to be lined up? Is that the key point.

Comment: It looks like something changed in a recent Sass update. Looking now to see how the new way works…

Answer (score 0):

I have used sass as pre-processor for css incorporating grid. At start I encountered several problems where the result was that no grid was presented. I thought first there was some limitation (in sass) about amount of content/lines in the "grid-template-area". I shrinked down the lines with same problem. Finally, after running a diff in a file comparison program I realized that sass is sensitive in terms of blank spaces. When cleaning out the white spaces between the block of "grid-template-areas" it started to work.